# msgraph-sdk-dotnet: Get HttpRequestMessage for Post/Put/Patch requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am aware of the GetRequestMessage() function on request objects in the .Net SDK.

Is it possible to get the request message of a non-get verb, that would include the request body?

Comment: We have been having a conversation about how to make this possible here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/issues/29#issuecomment-512804576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible.  This is something we would like to fix.